# OpenGL: how to get number of samples of a Texture

Tags: opengl

Given the OpenGL name of a texture, how do I query whether this texture is a multisample texture and how many samples it was allocated with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot query a texture object to find out [what its texture target is](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture#Theory). That's something you have to remember. So if you have been given some texture, and you don't know if it is a `GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE` or not, the *only* way to find out is to try to bind it as every single texture target. After each bind, check to see if you got an OpenGL error. If you *didn't*, then that's the right target.

Once you know what the target is, you can query the number of samples with `glGetTexLevelParameter` for mipmap level 0, using an enum of `GL_TEXTURE_SAMPLES`.

All of the above is true if you don't have access to ARB_direct_state_access/OpenGL 4.5. With those newer APIs, you don't have to know the texture's target anymore. You can just call `glGetTextureLevelParameter` on the texture object itself; if the `GL_TEXTURE_SAMPLES` parameter is zero, then it is not a multisample image.

Comment: While it looks like it's not needed in this case, I noticed in the spec that the texture target can be queried with `glGetTextureLevelParameter(GL_TEXTURE_TARGET, ...)` in OpenGL 4.5.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: ARB_direct_state_access introduces the `GL_TEXTURE_TARGET` query... while simultaneously introducing the API that makes it *completely pointless*. Irony, thy name is the ARB...

Comment: That should have been `glGetTextureParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_TARGET, ...)` in the previous comment. I guess there could be cases where it's useful, even though not here.

Comment: BTW, I believe the enum for the query is `GL_TEXTURE_SAMPLES`, not `GL_SAMPLES`.